# Date is displaying wrong

Tags: php

I have a date picker, when the date is selected and submitted, it displays a different date all together.

Ex: If I selected 04/20/2020 from the date picker and click submit,  the date that is displayed back is 01/01/1970.

Any idea why this is?

```
<form action="includes/generatelog.php" method="post"  name="generatelogform">
     Entries in the activity log will be generated for the date entered below.<br><br>
<label>Process Date: </label> <input id="flatpickr" name="date" value"">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="generatelog">Generate Log Entries</button>
```

generatelog.php:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "");
$db = mysqli_select_db($con, 'mydate');

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
if(isset($_POST['generatelog']))
{
  $date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($_POST["date"]));
  $day = date("l");

  echo "Today's date is ", $day,"\n", $date;
?>
```

This used to work, but now it doesn't. I'm not sure why it's displaying the wrong date.

Comment: Seems ok to me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c0525a1bc8a4efea6f4be409181928d9c28616e . So I'd assume that maybe it isn't submitting the value you expect in the $_POST["date"] value. Have you tried debugging to see what value is actually sent from the form?

Comment: What debug tool do you recommend? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Simple version, look in your browser's _Network_ developer console and check the data sent with the request to your PHP script

Comment: FYI, `mysqli_report()` should go **before** `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: Everything looks like it is sending the correct date from the from.

Comment: Ok so then use `var_dump($_POST["date"]);` in PHP to output what the received value actually looks like.

Comment: This is the result: string(10) "04-16-2020"

Comment: Ah, good old PHP date parsing. There's some pretty stupid code in `strtotime()` that interprets date strings with `/` as US format (mm/dd/yyyy) and with `-` as non-US (dd-mm-yyyy). Try using [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead

Comment: Same result as before.

Comment: show exactly how you used it please. Should be fine. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d44adc44819d4198d7c2ec959429577aadb2e706